# APEX sum different fields on a form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to create a page item display only that sums 2 other page itens on a form.

`P1_A` is a number field with a mask of currency.
`P1_B` is a display only field based on a database query that returns a single value.

My `P1_C` is a display only field that I am trying to use as a source the following query:
`select :P1_A+:P1_B from dual;`

However, this is my result :

```
Error computing item source value for page item P1_C.

ORA-01722: número inválido
Technical Info (only visible for developers)

    is_internal_error: true
    apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW_FORMS.ITEM_SOURCE_ERR
    ora_sqlcode: -1722
    ora_sqlerrm: ORA-01722: número inválido
    component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS
    component.id: 283302822642071708
    component.name: P1_C
    error_backtrace:

    ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1942
    ORA-06512: em "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL", line 1334
    ORA-06512: em "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL", line 1358
    ORA-06512: em "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL", line 1375
    ORA-06512: em "APEX_040100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 776
    ORA-06512: em "APEX_040100.WWV_FLOW_FORMS", line 580
```

I believe it has been caused by the currency format, but I can not remove it. So, what did I miss to avoid this error?

Comment: Could you please describe your workflow? What is a source for `P1_A` and `P1_B` - user input, DB, etc.?

Comment: `P1_A` is the single user input, while `P1_B` is based on a DB query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the text (P1_A) to number when using it in the sum calculations.

Example: `TO_NUMBER('$94 567,00', 'L999G999D00', NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ', ')`

Comment: I have used your solution here is my final code `SELECT :P1_B +TO_NUMBER(:P1_A, 'FML999G999G999G999G990D00')
  FROM dual` Thank you very much!